# how to get privileges for local infile command in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, cpanel

My script was working fine on localhost. However, when I uploaded it to my site, it turned out that I had no privileges for local infile variable. When I look it in PhpMyadmin, it shows "off" and I cannot edit it unlike localhost phpMyadmin. I tried to set this variable by SQL query as well as by PHP, but both times, it gave error that I was lacking SUPER privilege.

I searched the issue and found that one way of doing it is to have SUPER privilege. However, when I create a user in cpanel and assign it to a database, the cpanel gives me a list of privileges, but no option of SUPER privilege.

I really want to use this command. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: I have also read somewhere that I can change these variables from my.cnf file of mysql. I can see this file in my localhost directory. However, I don't know where to find it in the cpanel of website

Answer (score 0):

You need the FILE privilege to do it:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file

SUPER isn't necessary.

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. the problem is, I don't even have the file privilege. The privileges, available to me are:

 ALTER  CREATE
 CREATE ROUTINE  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES
 CREATE VIEW  DELETE
 DROP  EXECUTE
 INDEX  INSERT
 LOCK TABLES  REFERENCES
 SELECT  SHOW VIEW
 TRIGGER  UPDATE

Comment: Does your host provide root access to MySQL? If so, you could SSH into the server & use the command line mysql client to execute the grant manually -- GRANT FILE ON `dbn`.`tbn` TO 'user'@'localhost' -- or just do it via a php script (probably easier if you're not familiar with command line.)